# KeyError at /login/ 'is_login' Request Method: django

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSd2z.png)

I am coding web with django. I can not use session. I wanna check login use session

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.session['is_login'] == True:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
    else:
        next = request.POST.get('next', request.GET.get('next', ''))
        if request.method == "POST":
            username1 = request.POST.get('username')
            password1 = request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username1, password=password1)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    if next:
                        request.session['is_login'] = True
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(next)

                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')

                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Inactive user')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(LOGIN_URL)
        return render(request, "pages/login.html")
```

How to fix

Comment: try: `if request.session.get('is_login') == True:`

Comment: Thank you . I did execute follow you and successfully. :))

Comment: hey i use stack the frist time. :)) Help me vote for you and closed issue

Comment: But that is not how you use SO by copy pasting someone else solution.

Comment: @Ahtisham you should write this in an answer so OP can accept it.

Comment: @bfontaine Posted my answer and also added more information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments

change this:

```
if request.session['is_login'] == True:
```

to this:

```
if request.session.get('is_login') == True:
```

`request.session.get` does not raise `KeyError` It either returns the value at the key position or a `None` is returned.

You can also change the default behavior when a key is not found i.e instead of returning `None` you can return something else like this:

```
request.session.get('is_login', False)
```

The above statement will return `False` on failure instead of `None`.

visit [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views) for more information.

Comment: @DuyKhánhDeveloper Accept my answer as it fix your problem and gives you extra information of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

issue here is request.session doesn't have a key named is_login initially you are inserting that key when user successfully logs in so you need to add a check if key exists in session dict or not for that

use this

```
if 'is_login' in request.session and request.session['is_login'] == True:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making wrong check to see if the user is authenticated. If you want to see if an user is authenticated, simply do it by using [is_authenticated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated):

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
    else:
      # rest of the code
```

Also remove the line `request.session['is_login'] = True` because, django handles authentication itself. You don't need to use session to store that information.

Comment: I resolved it . Thank you very much. Your solution is very good

Comment: @DuyKhánhDeveloper By using `request.session.get('is_login')`, you are doing overwork, which is not necessary. Because django is doing that for you(checking and storing user authentication status in `request.user`). Also, django gives support to check if user is authenticated in [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/) as well, like `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`. Where you can't use `request.session.get('is_login')` in template

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all support me . I resolved
I did edit if request.session.get['is_login'] == True: to
  if request.session.get('is_login') == True:

Comment: @DDuyKhánhDeveloper Can you accept my answer ? You will get no points if you accept your own answer. So you should consider accept other's answer.